# making textbox readonly in javascript

Tags: javascript

I am having two radio buttons and two textbox. When I click on first checkbox, both texbox should not be readonly. But when I select second radio button it should make both text box readonly. I googled and found many solutions but don't know why none is not working in my code.
Html:

```
    <asp:RadioButton ID="mailNew" Text="New" runat="server" GroupName="mail_select" onclick="showHide(1)" ClientIDMode="Static" /><br />
    <asp:RadioButton ID="mailExisting" Text="Existing" runat="server" GroupName="mail_select" onclick="showHide(2)" ClientIDMode="Static" />

    <asp:TextBox ID="txtPromotion" runat="server" Width="77px" ></asp:TextBox><br />
    <asp:TextBox ID="txtSubject" runat="server" Width="288px"></asp:TextBox><br />
```

Javascript:

```
    function showHide(val) {
        var txtpid=document.getElementById(<% = txtPromotion %>)
        var txtsub= document.getElementById('<% = txtSubject.ClientID %>');
        if (val == 2) {
            txtpid.readOnly = false;
            txtsub.readOnly = false;
        }
        if (val == 1) {
            txtsub.setAttribute("readOnly.true");
            txtpid.setAttribute("readOnly,true");
        }
    }
```

Comment: can you check if the `txtpid` and `txtsub` variables are getting set or not? or are you getting any errors in the console? if so please paste it here

Comment: I am not getting any error..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see two issues:

1. You're not using `ClientID` for `txtPromotion`.
2. You're calling `setAttribute` with an incorrect attribute name and no value at all.

Just use the reflected property consistently in your code:

```
function showHide(val) {
    var txtpid=document.getElementById('<% = txtPromotion.ClientID %>')
    var txtsub= document.getElementById('<% = txtSubject.ClientID %>');
    if (val == 2) {
        txtpid.readOnly = false;
        txtsub.readOnly = false;
    }
    else if (val == 1) {
        txtsub.readOnly = true;
        txtpid.readOnly = true;
    }
}
```

Note that your code assumes `val` will never be anything other than `1` or `2`, because it doesn't update `readOnly` unless it's one of those two values. With that in mind, this might be cleaner:

```
function showHide(val) {
    document.getElementById('<% = txtPromotion.ClientID %>').readOnly = val == 1;
    document.getElementById('<% = txtSubject.ClientID %>').readOnly = val == 1;
}
```